# MAMP on macOS ventura 13.2 apple silicon M2 can't use port 80?

Tags: mamp, apple-silicon, macos-ventura

I try to use MAMP (v6.7) with apache on port 80.

Error: The port 80 is already in use

The Mac is a **fresh new install** without anything installed on it, **macOS 13.2** on M2 **apple silicon**.

If I try on other port like 8080 or 8888 it's ok, but I need port 80.

```
sudo lsof -P -n -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN

rapportd   398 eddy    4u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd21eb9      0t0  TCP *:52332 (LISTEN)
rapportd   398 eddy    8u  IPv6 0xe87a2134a3c715b1      0t0  TCP *:52332 (LISTEN)
ControlCe  426 eddy    5u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd413a9      0t0  TCP *:7000 (LISTEN)
ControlCe  426 eddy    6u  IPv6 0xe87a2134a3c706b1      0t0  TCP *:7000 (LISTEN)
ControlCe  426 eddy    7u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd429c9      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
ControlCe  426 eddy    8u  IPv6 0xe87a2134a3c70e31      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
cloud-dri  550 eddy   50u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd47739      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49156 (LISTEN)
cloud-dri  555 eddy    4u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd45609      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49154 (LISTEN)
cloud-dri  567 eddy    4u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd3bfe9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49158 (LISTEN)
cloud-dri  567 eddy   50u  IPv4 0xe87a21396cd47739      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49156 (LISTEN)
mysqld    4435 eddy   31u  IPv6 0xe87a2134a3c76fb1      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
```

I have tried the new "Indigo Stack" app with apache on port 80, exactly same error, the port 80 already in use.

How can I found what is listen on port 80?

Any idea? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On my M1Pro MacBook Pro, MacOS 13.2 I'm having the same issue.

As a temporary workaround, I've been able to get MAMP running using port 80 by using the scripts in the MAMP directory:

**Start**: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/start.sh` (this is same as clicking Start in MAMP)

**Stop**: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh`. (this is same as clicking Stop in MAMP)

There's a few other scrips in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/` that might be useful to check out.

Side note, I'm following this reported issue https://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=9913 for an offical fix (had to sign up to view :/ but there's a few more reports of the same issue this week so it's not an isolated issue)